# Transparent stage, solid attributes javafx

Tags: java, javafx, transparency, scenebuilder

I'm trying to create a javafx application (in scenebuilder).

How to get transparent stage, with solid items (buttons etc) on it? As it is done in [Windows 10 calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXb8B.jpg). The buttons are solid but the rest of the pane is transparent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have forgotten to include the question in your question. You've just stated what you've been doing, but we don't know what you are struggling with or what you need help with. Please read through [ask] and create a [MCVE] that focuses on the exact part of the issue you are struggling with so that we can help you.

Comment: Changed translucent to transparent. Meaning is the same, and all tech ppl will use transparent here. Maven tag removed, since has nothing to do here. Question provided

Answer (score 0):

To do that, **first**, you need to put the `scene` in a transparent `Stage` :

```
myStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

**Be aware:** if you do this, you need to use your own exit button, minimize buttons, because the titlebar will be gone.

**Then,** change the alpha channel of your scene to your desired, say 0.5:

```
scene.setFill(Color.rgb(0,26,0,0.5));
```

**and finally,** the root node's Background needs to be empty:

```
root.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
```

You are done. Now you can change the translucency of your application through the alpha variable.